# using the same view across pages

Tags: php, templates

I'm creating a micro MVC framework in PHP for my project. Actually it's only VC, I'm not using models, instead I do all the logic in the controller (including getting the data from mongodb).

I have a main Controller class with a function `renderView(...)` (which do some checks, extract the data array to variables and just call include() on every view) and all the controllers extend this class.

Also I wrote my own URL router where I can specify what url will call which method from which controller.
For example:

```
/          -> Home::index()
/users/:id -> Users::showProfilePage($id)
/settings  -> Users::showSettings()
```

etc.

In almost every method I'm loading the same views:

```
$this->renderView("header", "sidebar", <main view for the current page>, "footer", $data);
```

Now, my problem is that I want to use these views on a lot of pages, but for example `header` and `sidebar` need their own logic (PHP code). How can I achieve this without copying the php code for sidebar to every controller and method that is rendering the view `sidebar`?

Comment: Well .. if there is no model, then why the hell are you calling it "MVC"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're really looking for is how to manage repetitive template blocks. The idea behind block management is quite simple: You define `$blockName => $blockPath` pair and then juse use it inside another templates.

For example, you could define an array similar to this one:

```
$blocks = array(
  'footer' => __THEME_DIR__ . '/blocks/footer.phtml',
  'head'   => __THEME_DIR__ . '/block/header.phtnk'
);
```

And then use inside another templates, just like as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<?php $this->loadBlock('head'); ?>

<body>
  <main>
    ...
  </main>
  <?php $this->loadBlock('footer'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

That's the approach. But before you even start you need to setup those blocks for all so-called c
First of all - you need to avoid defining that `$blocks` array in each controller. To solve this, you can simple write `abstract` controller where you define `$blocks` only once, and then all descendants will inherit it.

For example,

```
<?php

abstract class AppPresenter extends FrameworkPresenter
{
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->view->registerBlocks(array(
              'header' => '....'
         ));
     }
}

class UserPresenter extends AppPresenter
{
     public function indexAction()
     {
        return $this->view->render('/index.phtml', array(
           'var' => 'val'
        ));
     }
}
```